# How to add less than (<) and greater than (>) in logback.xml

Tags: java, logback

Can someone let me know how can I add less than (<) and greater than (>) sign in `logback.xml`?

I want to have a `encoder.pattern` like below

```
<encoder>
 <pattern>%p [%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS}] %c{3}:[%C{1}:%M:%L] - [%t][%file:%line] - %replace(%.-20480m){'[^A-Za-z0-9=<>:@\\-\\[\\]\n\\s!]','_'}%n
 </pattern>
<encoder>
```

But this is failing because of the presence of `<>` ?

**EDIT**

My logback.xml looks like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- Scanning for changes in configuration file and automatic re-configuration -->
<configuration scan="true" debug="true">
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <Target>System.out</Target>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%p [%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS}] %c{3}:[%C{1}:%M:%L] - [%t][%file:%line] - %replace(%.-20480m){'[^A-Za-z0-9=&lt;&gt;:@\\-\\[\\]\n\\s!]','_'}%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Try escaping it with `&gt; and &lt;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&gt;
&lt;`

The XML standard escape sequence maybe helps.

Comment: I have escaped but now the line number is not showing up `INFO [2018-01-19 16:39:31] c.v.c.u.GCNotificationListener:[?:?:?] - [Service Thread] - GC_DETAILS _ ID=9_ GC_TYPE=end of minor GC_ GC_NAME=PS Scavenge_ DURATION_millis_=43_ GC_CAUSE=Allocation Failure_ GC_START_TIME_millsAfterJVMStart_=7198_ GC_END_TIME_millsAfterJVMStart_=7241`